# Check if row exists in different databases

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I want to create a rake task to check two different databases if same row exists:

**Database `abc`, table `shops`, column `partner_id`:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

**Database `xyz`, table `shops`, column `id`:**

```
1
2
4
5
6
```

I want to compare `abc.shops.partner_id` with `xyz.shops.id`. In such case, id `3` does not exist, and I will want to delete it.

Currently, I am just checking `abc.shops.partner_id` one by one, and if not found in `xyz`, then I will delete it. Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: What about this: get all the ids from database `xyz.shops` and put it in a `list`, and then remove all rows in `abc.shops` which rows does NOT have partner_id IN the given `list`? 2 queries.

Comment: Are these databases on the same server or different server? If they're on the same server you can join them.

Comment: @lucke84 Great idea! I shall consider!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they're on the same server, you can join the tables:

```
DELETE FROM abc.shops AS a
LEFT JOIN xyz.shops AS x ON a.partner_id = x.id
WHERE x.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all the shop ids from xyz using a single select query and delete the shops in abs if there is an id that is not in xyz's id list.

This way you are only firing two database queries.

Something like

```
 xyz_shop_ids = xyz.shops.pluck(:id)

 abc.shops.where("id NOT IN (?)", xyz_shops_ids).delete_all
```

Comment: Any way to improve performance? Because mysql2 gives me `MySQL server has gone away` while doing this on 500,000 rows.